# Guardar artículos en variables de sesión

Tags: php, html, css, session, cookies

tengo un problema en este programa de PHP, estoy intentando guardar en una variable de sesión una serie de productos que añado al carrito de compras, sin embargo, a pesar de que añada o compre varios, no me aparecen y solo sale como comprado al que le hago click desde mi index.
¿Alguna idea de como puedo guardar los productos en una variable de sesión y que se vayan acumulando?
He intentado crear varias variables de sesión para guardar los artículos, la cantidad y precio, guardándolos en un array pero no he tenido éxito y el fracaso es absoluto.

```css
<?php


//INICIO DE LA SESIÓN
session_start();

//SELECCIÓN DEL ARTICULO A COMPRAR

if (isset($_SESSION['tienda']) == true) {
    switch ($_POST['articulos']) {
        case "anais":
            $titulo = "Anaïs Nin. En un mar de mentiras";
            $precio = 1.50;
            break;
        case "invisible":
            $titulo = "Invisible Kingdom 1: En el camino";
            $precio = 0.50;
            break;
        case "jimy":
            $titulo = "Jimmy Olsen, el amigo de Superman";
            $precio = 3.00;
            break;
        case "once":
            $titulo = "Once and Future vol. 1: El rey ya no está muerto";
            $precio = 0.90;
            break;
        default:
            $error = "No has añadido nada";
            $precio = 0;
    }

    //CUANTAS CANTIDADES DEL ARTICULO VA A COMPRAR
    if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['cantidad'])) {
            $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
        }
    }
}

//FACTURA

if (isset($precio) && isset($_POST['cantidad'])) {
    $total = $cantidad * $precio;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Carrito - Práctica 1 - DWES</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="text-center bg-dark">
        <a><b class="text-info text-warning" style="font-size:30px;">
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION["tienda"])) {
                    echo "NOSTROMO";
                }
                //SESIÓN NO INICIADA
                else {
                    echo "No se ha iniciado la sesión";
                }
                ?></b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-5 contenedores">
        <div class="col-12 mt-2">
            <table class="table table-striped table-dark text-center" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" class="font-weight-bolder text-center">
                        <h4>Resumen de pedido:</h4>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if (!empty($_POST['articulos'])) {
                            echo $titulo;
                        } else {
                            echo $error;
                        }

                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php
                        if (!empty($_POST['cantidad'])) {
                            echo $cantidad;
                        } else {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                        ?></td>
                    <td><?php
                        if (!empty($precio) && isset($_POST['cantidad'])) {
                            echo $total;
                        } else {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                        ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-light" colspan="2">Total:</th>
                    <th class="text-light">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($precio) && isset($_POST['cantidad'])) {
                            echo $total . " €";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-light"> </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center col-12">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-info border-dark bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="inicio.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Volver a Comprar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info border-dark bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="gestionar.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Gestior Pedido</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/acdf8e9705.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Práctica 1 - DWES</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="text-center bg-dark">
        <a><b class="text-info text-warning" style="font-size:30px;">NOSTROMO</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-4 col-12">
                <h1 class="text-light text-center"><u>Tienda de Cómics</h1></u>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="carrito.php" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label for="selecciona" class="col-form-label text-light">Selecciona un cómic:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="articulos">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="anais">Anaïs Nin. En un mar de mentiras</option>
                                <option value="invisible">Invisible Kingdom 1: En el camino</option>
                                <option value="jimy">Jimmy Olsen, el amigo de Superman</option>
                                <option value="once">Once and Future vol. 1: El rey ya no está muerto</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-mt-2">
                            <label for="cantidad" class=" col-form-label text-light">Cantidad:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" size="10" max="10" min="1" value="0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mx-auto mt-4 col-8 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info bg-danger" value="Añadir a la cesta" name="btnAgregar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo no veo que guardes nada en tu variable de sesión. ¿Nos puedes decir en qué parte de tu código crees que guardas algo? Además, eso de *crear varias variables de sesión* no tiene sentido.

Comment: No he añadido esa parte del código porque sale error. Quiero guardar varias variables de sesión para poder guardar articulo, cantidad y precio

Comment: Precisamente debes añadir la parte que da error, para poder ayudarte a solucionar dicho error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los que buscas lo puede solucionar con un `array` en la variable de `sesion` que es mas optimo.

```html
<?php
session_start();  
/*El inicio de sesion debe ir inmediatamente despues de la apertura php  para evitar posibles errores */



/*SELECCIÓN DEL ARTICULO A COMPRAR esto se desencadena mediante una accion.
ya sea click en un boton  y por el metodo POST o GET.
en tal caso  deberiamos revisar eso */


if(isset($_POST['miboton'])){
   
   //si ya hay articulos igualamos , si no creamos un arreglo vacio
   if(isset($_SESSION['tienda']) $compra = $_SESSION['tienda'] ;
   else $compra = [];

    switch ($_POST['articulos']) {
        case "anais":
            if(isset($compra["anais"]))  $compra["anais"]["cantidad"]++;
            else{
                $compra["anais"] = [
                     "titulo" => "Anaïs Nin. En un mar de mentiras",
                     "cantidad" => 1,
                     "precio" => "1.50"
               ];
            }
            break;
        case "invisible":
            if(isset($compra["invisible"]))  $compra["invisible"]["cantidad"]++;
            else{
                $compra["invisible"] = [
                     "titulo" => "invisible estoy",
                     "cantidad" => 1,
                     "precio" => "2"
               ];
            }
        case "jimy":
           if(isset($compra["Jimmy"]))  $compra["v"]["cantidad"]++;
            else{
                $compra["v"] = [
                     "titulo" => "Jimmy Olsen, el amigo de Superma",
                     "cantidad" => 1,
                     "precio" => "1.50"
               ];
            }
            break;
        default:
           echo "No has añadido nada";
    }
  //Guardamos el arreglo modifcado en la variable de sesion
  $_SESSION['tienda'] = $compra;
  
}
```

Para recorrer el arreglo:

```html
if(is_array($_SESSION["tienda"]){

  foreach($_SESSION["tienda"] as $k => $valor){
      var_dump($valor);
  }


}
```

O bien simplemente acceder mediante la `key`

```html
var_dump($_SESSION["tienda"]["Jimmy"]);
```

De todos modos. te recomiendo pasar la lógica a una función.